# International student going to Canada

Tags: canada, students, covid-19

Is it possible for international students who are newly admitted to Canadian universities for the September 2020 intake allowed in to the country amidst the Covid-19 pandemic?

I already know that the classes will be conducted online, but I am just not sure if I am allowed to go to Canada and conduct my online classes there, because if thats not possible I will rather take a gap year instead.

FYI i did not know what other stackexchange site I could use to ask this question so I asked here as I will be an expatriate soon if I am allowed in to Canada.

I will appreciate the clarification.

Comment: Oh i see no problem but thanks for the feedback, was not sure how to ask around ok forums even though i checked the immigration site. Just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [IRCC](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/coronavirus-covid19/visitors-foreign-workers-students.html)

> If you’re an international student who has a valid study permit, or
>   were approved for a study permit on or before March 18, 2020, **you’re
>   exempt from the travel restrictions.**

They also mention that:

> When you arrive in Canada, we’ll assess your health before you leave
>   the port of entry. You must have a plan to quarantine for 14 days when
>   you arrive in Canada. This is mandatory, even if you have no symptoms.
>
> If you don’t have a plan, you shouldn’t travel to Canada.

So, in short if you had an approved study permit on or before March 18, 2020, you’re exempt from the travel restrictions, otherwise you cannot travel to Canada. Also prepare to have a place where you can quarantine yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Upvoted, and my previous comment deleted.